# List alignment issue css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a vertical progress bar but I keep encountering problems with the list. Everything appears okay from the 1st to the 9th child. However, from the 10th child the :before content becomes circular and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code...

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <style>
    .list_progress_bar {
      counter-reset: step;
      padding: 40px 0px;
      margin: 0;
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li:before {
      content: counter(step);
      color: red;
      counter-increment: step;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 1%;
      background-color: #ddd;
      z-index: -1;
      top: -60px;
      left: 35px;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li.first_child:after {
      content: none;
    }
    .list_progress_ba li:not(:first-child) {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li a {
      margin-left: 55px;
      margin-top: -39px;
      padding: 0px 5px;
      border: 1px solid #c7c6c2;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #7b7a76;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #dedcd4;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li.active:before {
      border-color: #008dcb;
      background-color: #008dcb;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .list_progress_bar li.active + li:after {
      background-color: #008dcb;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <ul class="list_progress_bar">


    <li class="active first_child">
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="lister" list-video-id="h14wr4pXZFk" style="cursor: pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
    </li>


    <br>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post all your code, HTML included

Comment: I have posted it including a snippet.

Comment: There are no mistakes in your code. That is because, from 10 and above, there are characters like, 1 and 0, 1 and 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The double digits are causing problems as the padding kind of increases

Now you can add

```
Position:absolute;
min-width: 20px;//or whatever value yo see suitable
```

On your .list_progress_bar li:before

Then increase the left on both your 
.list_progres_bar_li a and .list_progress_bar li:after

Answer (score 0):

Alright.

After a little more work. I finally discovered the solution to my own problem and just wanna share anyway.

```
.list_progress_bar li:nth-child(-n+12):before
{
    padding:  10px 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error related to css u written. Actually when it reach 10 size of width increase. As there is just one digit till 9 and after that div contain 2 digits so ur border radius assigned become nearly equal to half of its width and look like circle. Just play with either width of div or radius to make it equal for everyone. Either use border radius in %.